# Jquery Ajax POST to C# WebMethod Errors with "Invalid JSON primitive: System.Object."

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax

Morning all. I've been trying to do this for weeks now but keep going in circles. I have a simple jQuery Ajax function that POSTS Data to a c# function in the code behind.

Basically want to pass a list of selected checkbox fields to be processed. 
When I submit it, I can see the request being made and the json being sent:

```
{"item":["Section1","Section2","Section2Sub1","Section2Sub2","Section3"]}
```

It gets to the server side but when trying to deserialize it, it kicks me back the following error message:

> "Invalid JSON primitive: System.Object."

```
var selection = serializer.Deserialize<string>(item.ToString());
```

Here's my code snippet:

```
 

client side
 $("#Submit").click(function (e) {

                    var count = 0;
                    var countChecked = 0;

                    areaObj = [];
                    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
                        count++;
                        if (this.checked) {
                            //countChecked++;
                            //tmp = {
                            //    "Area": $(this).attr("id")
                            //};
                            areaObj.push($(this).attr("id"));
                        }
                    });
                 });

 function subClick(item) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/SubData",
                data: JSON.stringify({ item: item }),
                //data: "{'item':" + JSON.stringify(item) + "}",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            });
        };

c# Default.aspx.cs
[WebMethod]
        public static string SubData(Selection item)
        {
            var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            //ERROR OCCURS HERE
            var selection = serializer.Deserialize(item.ToString());

            return "this is successful";
        }

 public class Selection
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List KeyValues { get; set; }
    }
    public class KeyValues
    {
        public int AreaID { get; set; }
        public string Area { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Can anyone offer any pointers on what is going wrong?

Comment: Your use of `item.ToString()` indicates to me that you're not actually parsing the json you think you are. You're parsing the text `System.Object` which is the result of `.ToString()` on an object. If you put a breakpoint on the deserialize line, you'll see that `item` is not a string.

Comment: It further looks like `item` is *already* the deserialized object.

Comment: *slaps forehead*  Of course it is. I've spent so long looking at this I became a bit snow blind to it.... Thanks Rob! Can you "Answer the question" and i'll mark it as the solution

Comment: No worries mate, happy it helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static string SubData(Selection item)
{
    var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    //ERROR OCCURS HERE
    var selection = serializer.Deserialize(item.ToString());
    return "this is successful";
}
```

Here, `item` is not a string (and thus not the JSON being sent). Since you're calling `ToString()` on it, it's likely the library is trying to deserialize text similar to `System.Object` - which will fail.

At a quick glance at the code, it looks like `item` is already deserialized for you, so you don't need to do anything further